# Multiple bridge network in docker?

Tags: linux, apache, docker, devops, docker-network

I have a physical server with two networks:

```
- eth0: with IP: x.x.x.x for public network
- eth1: with IP: y.y.y.y for local network
```

Now I deploy a docker container in this server. But I want to public `port 1024` for receive data through `eth1` and public port 80 for access `web UI (apache)` through `eth0`.

How can I configure multiple bridge network in docker and start it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not need another bridge network. If you're already publishing ports with bridge networking, the solution may be simple as telling Docker which address to use for each port:

```
docker run yada yada -p x.x.x.x:80:80 -p y.y.y.y:1024:1024
```